# Password Issues

Tags: password

In the Ubuntu installation process I have selected the option to start placing the password, after installing Ubuntu, when I entered my password I got a message saying that it was wrong, I changed the password but I still got the same error, so I reinstalled Ubuntu and selected the option to enter automatically without asking the password ... I was carrying out the process of installing an application from the terminal and when entering the password I get to try again ... I am sure that I am entering the correct password but Ubuntu does not recognize it.

What could I do? Thanks: D

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is an English Language Only website.  Please only post in English, even if you have to run your post through a translator first.  (I've done a Google Translate on your post already)

Comment: I suppose it is keyboard layout issue. I've  experienced such trouble last week. Try to enter in the [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) and [change your password](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nnxj7osSjNU).